# "See (someone) back" is idiom?

Tags: idioms

> Well, I guess you might think that, but when I **saw it back** then
>   it was anything **but** boring!

Am I right that "**saw (someone) back**" is idiom?

Why is **but** used before **boring**? Maybe, it should be something like: *"...it was nothing boring!"*

Comment: _Anything but_ is an idiom meaning _the opposite of_.

Answer (score 4):

**back then** is a colloquial idiom in English that means: at that time.

It is not: saw someone back, it is saw someone **back then.**

Comment: From [*back*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/back#h2): "(adverb) **1 b** : in or into the past : backward in time … // ***Back then***, no one had ever heard of chronic fatigue syndrome."

Comment: To explicate a bit further:  to "see someone back" is indeed an idiom.  "Jack saw Jill back to the store" means that Jack escorted her to the store.  It is not, however, the idiom used here.

Comment: I will see you back to the door. Sure. But, back then is an idiom.